# Prove Q is open using the square metric.

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $Q=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|y>x^2\}$. Using the square metric provide a value for $\delta$ so that for any point $(x_0,y_0)\in Q$ the ball $B_{\delta}(x_0,y_0))\subset Q$.

The square metric is given by,
\begin{align*}
d((x,y),(a,b))=max\{|x-a|,|y-b|\}.
\end{align*}
I am just so unfamiliar working with the square metric I am having trouble getting a handle on how to compute a specific $\delta$. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you do it with the usual metric?

Comment: This metric is more commonly known as $L_\infty$. In order for the distance between two points to be less than $\delta$, each coordinates' values must be less than $\delta$ away from each other. 

A point in $Q$ can be represented by $(x,x^2+\epsilon)$ for some $x\in\mathbb R, \epsilon\in\mathbb R^+$. Can you take it from here?